# Change of limits in integral - Tricky substitution in polar coordinates

Tags: integration

I observed a transition between two steps that I can't figure out how it was done. I hope someone better skilled in identifying this could provide the clue.

Particularly, I did not get how $\theta_z$ got into the limits and under what conditions that is possible

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a single-variable calculus substitution of the form $\theta_x = \theta + c$, where $d\theta_x = d\theta$ and you change the bounds of integration as you always do ($\theta_x=a$ corresponds to $\theta=a-c$, and similarly for $b$):
$$
\int_a^b f(\theta_x) \, d\theta_x = \int_{a-c}^{b-c} f(\theta + c) \, d\theta.
$$
No assumptions needed, you can always do this.

However, there is something a bit weird here. Since $c = \theta_z$ in this case, the new integral should have been
$$
\int_{-\theta_z}^{2\pi-\theta_z} \cdots
$$
rather than
$$
\int_{\theta_z}^{2\pi+\theta_z} \cdots
.
$$
However, since the integrand is $2\pi$-periodic, the integral over *any* interval of length $2\pi$ gives the same result, so the formula is actually true as it stands, but it's hard to tell if this was intentional or just “luck”.

Comment: Thanks so much for this explicit answer. It is very well appreciated

Comment: You're welcome!